# How to save multi-selected options into an array within React state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to save both team members in select into an array within a state object. My expectation would be to be able to ctrl-click the options and this would update state (using the on change handler). For right now I have this, which only ends up saving the first option in state:

> setProjectDetails((prevState) => ({
> ...prevState,
> [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
> }));

I'm working with a mongoose/mongodb backend, so the id's are associated with the team members. I'm looking for the state to end up like this:

> const initialProjectDetails = {
> title: "test",
> description: "test",
> teamMembers: ["628c0133e5edf7b21cd8f31b", "628c0133e5edf7b21cd8f31b"],    };

Form:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to update the desired key in the object (teamMembers):

```js
setProjectDetails((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, teamMembers: e.target.value, }));
```